# SailsJs Partial disable Restful API

Tags: sails.js

Suppose I have 3 models A, B, C. Is there any way to enable rest API for model C only?

blueprints.js can only turn on/off the rest API function for all models.

I think if it can't be configured, a controller is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need a controller to override the configurations of your blueprints, since you only want one model to have rest API, then you can set it to false(globally) in your blueprint settings, and for that particular model(C), you create a controller and add a custom `_config` property that will override what was set in the blueprints settings.

Like this

```
var ModelController = {
  _config: {
    actions: true,
    shortcuts: true,
    rest: true
  }
}
module.exports = ModelController
```

According to the docs the opposite is true (dissabling), and its what i've tried in the past, but i believe it will work like this. If not, you'll have to enable the restApi for all of them and disable it for all but your model C controller.

This is the link to the docs related to that http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api

I'm not aware of any other option right now, but let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, it works. In this way, there is no configuration in routes.js. Then how to apply a policy to all the action of this model?

Comment: Assuming you are using 1 controller for your C model, you have to add the controller name as a key in your `policies.js` file and add the actions (or a wildcard *) you want to be affected by your policy. IMHO the documentation is pretty clear on that http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/policies . I'll appreciate if you mark this as the correct answer since it solved what you asked :)